# How to resume back the media on the same position before the activity was paused

Tags: android

```
package com.ingenvis.omkareshwar;

public class MantraActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnPreparedListener, MediaController.MediaPlayerControl, View.OnClickListener{
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar;
    ScrollView sv;
private static final String TAG = "AudioPlayer";
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private MediaController mediaController;
private String audioFile;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
int length,length1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mantra);
    
    Log.d("Reached here ", "Reached here");
    
//  Button playButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    TextView headingMantra2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textHeading);
    TextView mantra2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_Mantra);
    TextView meaningTitleMantra2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_mean);
    TextView meaningMantra2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textMeaning);
            
    sv = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
    sv.scrollTo(0, 0);
    
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("मंत्र ");
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.om);
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#707069")));

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.record20140514130231);
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mediaController = new MediaController(this);
```

//      mediaController.show();

```
    headingMantra2.setOnClickListener(this);
    mantra2.setOnClickListener(this);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    meaningTitleMantra2.setOnClickListener(this);
    meaningMantra2.setOnClickListener(this);
    

    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

}

 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home: {
                 Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    startActivityIfNeeded(intent, 0);
                    return true;
            }
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
 
 
 @Override
  public void onPause(){
     super.onPause();
     pause();
 }
 
 @Override
 public void onResume(){
     super.onResume();
     resume();
 }

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    mediaController.show();
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
       mediaController.show();
    
}


@Override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    mediaController.hide();
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.release();
//  mediaPlayer = null;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mantra, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mediaController.setMediaPlayer(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.button2));
}

@Override
public void start() {
    mediaPlayer.start();
}

public void play(View v){
    start();
}



@Override
public void pause() {
    mediaPlayer.pause();
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("<com.ingenvis.omkareshwar>", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    mediaPlayer.pause();
    length = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    length1 = mediaPlayer.getDuration();

    editor.putInt("length", length); //assuming length is an integer
    editor.putInt("length1", length);
    editor.commit();
}

public void resume(){
     SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("<com.ingenvis.omkareshwar>", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int length = prefs.getInt("length", 0); //0 is the default value

//      mediaPlayer.start();
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(length);
}
@Override
public int getDuration() {
    return mediaPlayer.getDuration();
}


@Override
public int getCurrentPosition() {
    return mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
}

@Override
public void seekTo(int pos) {
    mediaPlayer.seekTo(pos);
    
}

@Override
public boolean isPlaying() {
    return mediaPlayer.isPlaying();

}

@Override
public int getBufferPercentage() {
    
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean canPause() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean  canSeekBackward() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean canSeekForward() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public int getAudioSessionId() {
    return 0;
}



public void onBackPressed(){
//  mediaPlayer.stop();
    finish();
}
```

}

Comment: This is my log which i am getting

Answer (score 1):

You can store and retrieve the value of `length` using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Here's your modified `onPause()`

```
@Override
public void pause() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("<com.your.app>", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    mediaPlayer.pause();
    length = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    length1 = mediaPlayer.getDuration();

    editor.putInt("length", length); //assuming length is an integer
    editor.putInt("length1", length1); //you should put different values in different variable
    editor.commit();
}
```

And you can read it back in your `onResume()` like this

```
public void resume(){
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("<com.your.app>", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int length = prefs.getInt("length", 0); //0 is the default value

    mediaPlayer.start();
    mediaPlayer.seekTo(length);
}
```

Comment: this is the error shown in log                                                                   11-14 01:47:45.827: E/AndroidRuntime(1898): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.ingenvis.omkareshwar/com.ingenvis.omkareshwar.MantraActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException

Comment: @AnilManchanda post your new code in the question and also the logcat.

Comment: 11-14 01:47:45.827: E/AndroidRuntime(1898): Process: com.ingenvis.omkareshwar, PID: 1898
11-14 01:47:45.827: E/AndroidRuntime(1898): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.ingenvis.omkareshwar/com.ingenvis.omkareshwar.MantraActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException
11-14 01:47:45.827: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2788)
11-14 01:47:45.827: E/AndroidRuntime(1898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)

Comment: This is the log i am getting

Comment: @AnilManchanda can you post the complete logcat as a part of your question? The above doesnt help me understand what is causing the problem.

Comment: this is my log which i am getting

Comment: android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
11-17 00:57:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1369):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-17 00:57:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1369):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-17 00:57:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1369):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
11-17 00:57:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1369):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

Comment: 11-17 00:57:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1369):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-17 00:57:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1369):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
11-17 00:57:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1369):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
11-17 00:57:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1369):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: 11-17 00:57:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1369):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-17 00:57:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1369): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
11-17 00:57:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1369):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.seekTo(Native Method)
11-17 00:57:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1369):  at com.ingenvis.omkareshwar.MantraActivity.onResume(MantraActivity.java:109)
11-17 00:57:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1369):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1192)
11-17 00:57:33.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1369):  at

Comment: This is the full log which i am getting

Answer (score 0):

In onPause(), save the current position of the player, e.g. in shared preferences. In onResume(), retrieve the value and then use MediaPlayer.seekTo() to position.

[This developer.android.com link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#seekTo(int)) may give you more insights.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {

Log.d(App.TAG, "onPause called");

if(mMediaPlayer==null){
    Log.d(App.TAG, "Returning from onPause because the mediaplayer is null");
    super.onPause();
    return;
}

// the OS is pausing us, see onResume() for resume logic
settings = getSharedPreferences(Dawdle.TAG, MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor ed = settings.edit();
mMediaPlayer.pause();
ed.putInt("LAST_POSITION", mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());  // remember where we are
ed.putBoolean("PAUSED", true); 
ed.commit();
Log.d(App.TAG, "LAST_POSITION saved:" + mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());

super.onPause();
releaseMediaPlayer();

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
  Log.d(App.TAG, "onResume called");

try {

    if (mMediaPlayer==null){
        setupMediaPlayer();
    }

    // if we were paused (set in this.onPause) then resume from the last position
    settings = getSharedPreferences(Dawdle.TAG, MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (settings.getBoolean("PAUSED", false)) {
        // resume from the last position
        startPosition= settings.getInt("LAST_POSITION", 0);
        Log.d(App.TAG,"Seek to last position:" + startPosition);
    }

    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
    mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);

    // this is key, the call will return immediately and notify this when the player is prepared through a callback to onPrepared
    // so we do not block on the UI thread - do not call any media playback methods before the onPrepared callback
    mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();  

} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}

private void startVideoPlayback() {
   Log.v(App.TAG, "startVideoPlayback at position:" + startPosition);
   mMediaPlayer.seekTo(startPosition);
   mMediaPlayer.start();
}
```